# What's the AWS SDK V2 class for Lambda S3Event?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, maven, aws-lambda, aws-sdk

For the Java SDK V1, I have a lambda function like this:

```
public static void doSomethingLambda(S3Event s3Event) throws Exception {
    s3Event....
```

however in SDK V2, `S3Event` does not seem to exist. Unless I am using the wrong dependency? (The docs for V2 are pretty sparse)

Here is my SDK V1 Dependencies:

```
  <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-lambda-java-events</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-s3</artifactId>
        <version>1.11.534</version>
    </dependency>
```

and SDK V2:

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
        <artifactId>s3</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
        <artifactId>lambda</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: It's January 2020 and I can't find _any_ examples of SDK 2.0 Lambda Functions in Java.

Comment: it's Feb 2020 and I no answer from AWS yet. also I have tried to use the v1 S3Event but I been getting an empty obj back

Comment: Why not use the java events library directly? Version 3.0.0+ (specifically 3.6.0) is now out and it includes ALL the events, include `S3Events` - https://github.com/aws/aws-lambda-java-libs/tree/master/aws-lambda-java-events

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/61157061/843660

Answer (score 6):

According to the resolution provided on 18 May for [aws lambda java libs to aws sdk java v2](https://github.com/aws/aws-lambda-java-libs/issues/74)

```
aws-lambda-java-events version 3.0.0 was just released with support for all events (including S3) without the inclusion of SDK v1 dependencies.
This should help you make use of the AWS SDK for Java v2 and reduce your function package size as the v1 SDK does not need to be bundled anymore if it's not explicitly needed.
```

Source code is [here](https://github.com/aws/aws-lambda-java-libs)